# Why did the author used the intersection of the line $y = tx$ with the curve to find the parametrisation?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

I want to parametrize the curve $y^2=x^2+x^3.$ When I was reading the textbook by Theodore Shifrin "DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY:A First Course in Curves and Surfaces". I found the parametrisation as
$x(t)=t^2-1, y(t)=t(t^2-1). $ Why did the author used the intersection of the line $y = tx$ with the curve to find the parametrisation?

**My attempt:-**

We have $y^2=x^2+x^3$. Put $y=tx$, we get $(tx)^2 = x^2(x + 1).$

That is $t^2x^2-x^2.x-x^2 = 0\implies x^2(t^2-x-1)=0.$
That is either $x=0$ or $x=t^2-1$. Then author assumed $t\ge 0$, the got $y=t(t^2-1)$.

Can I parametrize in different way? When I tried to parametrize using $x=t$. I am not getting a functional relation for $y$ which covers the curve.

Could you help me?

Comment: If you use $x=t$ then you get $y=\pm \sqrt{t^2+t^3}$ with two problems: it is not single -valued and it does not give real values when $t <-1$

Comment: @Henry Why did the author used such strange parametrization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author did not come up with this by divine inspiration. This is a classical construction, going back hundreds of years. The idea is this: The curve $y^2=x+x^3$ is a cubic curve, so you expect a line to intersect it in three points. (Draw some pictures and verify this for yourself.) The origin is a double point of the curve (you can see that two "branches" cross there) and so lines passing through the origin will intersect the curve at a unique point other than the origin — the origin uses up two of the three points.

Comment: "The author" indeed. :)

Comment: Does line always intersect the cubic curves at three points?

Comment: Let $y=mx+b$ be the line. $(mx+b)^2=x+x^2=m^2x^2+2mbx+b^2=x^3+x^2\implies x^3+(1-m^2)x^2-2mbx-b^2=0$ which is a cubic equation. I know every cubic equation have at least one real root. What if other zeroes are complex?

Comment: Yes, what I said is literally true only over the complex numbers and including points at infinity. But it is nevertheless the origin of the parametrization of this rational curve. Note that even for lines through the origin, the third point in which the vertical line meets the curve is the point at infinity.